# What does "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved." mean?

Tags: support, locking

As an example, look at [Can commented-out code be valuable documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190096/can-commented-out-code-be-valuable-documentation).

Why has it been locked, what does "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved." mean, and what can we do about it?

The "For more info visit meta" link attached to the notice just points to the meta site itself and not a particular question or answer, the comments don't say anything, and a search on meta has not been fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a moderator will lock a post for one of a few reasons:

> A question or answer where repeated voting or editing is happening in a way which attempts to game, hack, or otherwise abuse the system.
>
> A question that gets opened and closed repeatedly many times without achieving community consensus on whether it should stay open or closed.
>
> A question that, for whatever reason, continues to attract flame posts, spam, or other inappropriate answers.
>
> A question that is repeatedly vandalized by its asker; for example, to drastically alter the meaning of the question that invalidates existing answers, or to obliterate/obscure the question.

See [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

I locked the post temporarily because it was closed as a duplicate by community consensus, then started to receive flags disputing that it was in fact **not** a duplicate of the following question....

[Is commented out code really always bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45378/is-commented-out-code-really-always-bad)

I felt as if I agreed with this, however it had over 10 answers already and at the other over 13.  I couldn't really see too much else of value being added in addition to what others have already answered well and completely.  I was hoping that with a temporary lock that it wouldn't attract anymore answers and if anybody was concerned or highly disagreed with my reopen of the question then they would bring the subject up on Meta for us to discuss.

I am glad that you brought it up because this question can be the perfect vehicle for such a discussion.

Comment: I unlocked the question. There was no content dispute here, I get what you tried to do, but the lock simply isn't the appropriate tool for it. If you feel the question should stay open, but the answers are problematic, then moderate the answers. If you think the current answers are great, but the question doesn't need any more answers, moderate any future answers _if_ they appear.